# How to return pageableResponseInfo object from Domain Resolver class to Controller class?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

How to return pageableResponseInfo object from DomainArgumentResolver class to Controller class?
I have given all the classes below.

Here is the PageableResponseInfo object. I want to get the invalidSortParam value  in the controller class.

```
public class PageableResponseInfo  {
    private String invalidSortParam;
    public PageableResponseInfo(String invalidSortParam){
        this.invalidSortParam = invalidSortParam;
    }
    public String getInvalidSortParam() {
        return this.invalidSortParam;
    } 
}
```

Component class:
This class is doing some business logic and populating the PageableInfo object.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties
public class DomainArgumentResolver extends SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver {
    PageableResponseInfo pageableResponseInfo;

    @Override
    public Sort resolveArgument() {
        pageableResponseInfo = new PageableResponseInfo();
        // ...
        if (orders.size() <= paramSize) { 
            pageableResponseInfo.setInvalidSortParam(order.getProperty() + " is not a valid sort parameter");
        }
        // ...  
        return sort;
    } 
}
```

Controller class
Below is the controller class where I want the PageableResponseInfo Object through DomainArgumentResolver class.

```
@RestController
public class JsonDbController {
    @Autowired
    private DomainArgumentResolver domainArgumentResolver;

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> getAllBooks(Pageable pageable) {
        List<Book> bookList;
        ApiResponse response;
        try {
            if (domainArgumentResolver != null) {
                response = ApiResponse.ofFailure("ji");
            } else {
                bookList = bookService.findAllBooks(pageable);
                response = ApiResponse.ofSuccess(bookList, "All books fetched successfully");
            }
        } 
        catch (InvalidSortException e) {
            response = ApiResponse.fromException(e);
            logger.error("Failed . Cause: {}", e);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            response = ApiResponse.ofFailure("Failed to fetch books. Please try again");
            logger.error("Failed to fetch all books. Cause: {}", e);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(response, org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.valueOf(response.getCode()));
    }
}
```

Please let me know if any other information is required.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a getter method for `PageableResponseInfo` in your `DomainArgumentResolver` class so when you autowired aforementioned class in your controller you can get the object of `PageableResponseInfo` object.

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties
Public class DomainArgumentResolver extends SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver {
                PageableResponseInfo pageableResponseInfo;

                @Override
                public Sort resolveArgument() {
                   //your code
                }
                public PageableResponseInfo getPageableResponseInfo(){
                    return this.pageableResponseInfo;
                }
       }
```

Rest Controller:

```
@RestController
public class JsonDbController {
    @Autowired
    private DomainArgumentResolver domainArgumentResolver;

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> getAllBooks(Pageable pageable) {
        PageableResponseInfo pageableResponseInfo = domainArgumentResolver.getPageableResponseInfo();
        //other stuff
    }
}
```

Hope this what you are looking for :)

Comment: How can I write a test case to check this functionality?Please help!